# Why doesn't my image color match background color in FireFox?

Tags: firefox, colors, jpeg, photoshop

I think I could be doing something wrong in photoshop.  I'm trying to create a banner for my website.

I created a new image in photoshop, then filled the background with a color I picked #E06205

I then saved the image as a jpeg.

On my webpage, I created a div and gave it a background color
background-color:#E05206;

When I open the page in Safari and Chrome it's beautiful.  Matches perfectly.

However, when I open the page in FireFox, the colors don't match.  I can't figure out why that is.

[image]

By the way, this is definitely a problem with the image I created.  When I compare the same image side by side, Firefox gives me the 'wrong' color
[image]

Comment: Can you show the jpeg file in question? What OSs is this on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is in the color profile you are using for the image.  Make sure when you save the image you use **Save for Web & Devices…**

To read more if you want you could travel to this website:
http://css-tricks.com/color-rendering-difference-firefox-vs-safari/

Answer (score 1):

You should save your images with "Save for Web & Devices" option of "File" menu in Photoshop. You can get many options and image types in this option as per your requirement.